# Component render but not call Lifecycle functions

Tags: reactjs

I have a project that creates a HTML layout based on json file

**On the 4th and 3th step, some components are not call lifecycle functions**

### For Example

#### Component code

[image: Component code]

BaseNode – that is empty class

#### Rendering result

[image]

#### Console output

[image]

#### Mini project with reproducible error:

[project](https://github.com/kirsanv43/ReactJsIssue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Full answer here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6144)

It was necessary to replace key={i} on key={Math.random()}